# Font styled with CSS and JQuery corrupted in Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome

My client notified me today regarding a strange issue that affects the website in only Google Chrome. The website, for reference, is www.circom.co.uk. The issue is related to the text displayed in the animated image banner at the top of the page.

When the site is viewed with a browser other than Chrome, the site displays perfectly. Below is a screenshot of the site taken with Internet Explorer 11:
[image]

However, I've tried the site on Google Chrome on Windows 8.1, and this is how it displays the site: 
[image]

I had been meaning to update Google Chrome on my Debian 7 install, but I hadn't got round to it. However, the version of Chrome on Debian displayed the page perfectly, a lot like the IE11 image. The version of Chrome on Debian is 36.0.1985.125, the version of Chrome where the site is broken is version 37.0.2062.120 m.

I believe this to be a bug with Chrome, and I've reported it as so. However, in case Google think this is a feature, what can I do to fix the text in Chrome?

***EDIT:***
Here is the JavaScript that does the animation:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#home_banners').each(function() {
            $(this).cycle({
                fx:     'fade',
                speed:  700,
                timeout: 6000,
                after: onAfter,
                before: onBefore
              });
            });

            function onAfter(curr, next, opts, fwd) {
            $('.green-box').delay(300).animate({ left: 0 }, { duration: 300});
            $('.caption').delay(300).animate({ right: 0 }, { duration: 300});
            $('.caption h2').delay(500).animate({ right: '80px' }, { duration: 300});
            }

            function onBefore(curr, next, opts, fwd) {                  
            $('.green-box').animate({ left: '-873px'}, { duration: 500});
            $('.caption').animate({ right: '873px'}, { duration: 500});        
            $('.caption h2').animate({ right: '875px'}, { duration: 500});
            }
                  });
</script>
```

The library can be found here: [enter link description here](http://www.circom.co.uk/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/js/jquery.cycle.js)

Comment: The problem here is using any version of IE as your control ;)

Comment: I was kidding, of course.  I just went to the linked site... it looks like the slide animation is not properly rendering... it sort of *smears* it's contents and doesn't re-render as it moves, just kinda draws over what was already there.  Can you link some example JS?  It would be best if you could give us a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Ah the first comment made me smile! I've updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't help but notice the site URL in your screenshot.

It appears to occur with this line of CSS applied to the  tag on the slider elements:

```
.green-box .caption-wrapper .caption h2 {
position: absolute;
}
```

Removing it will fix the issue, but then you will need to re-evaluate how you are positioning that text.

Comment: You're correct, that does seem to be causing the issue. I'm playing with it now to see if I can make a change to the CSS that doesn't break the other browsers.